# Issue with Postgresql 13.0 compilation on CentOS 8,7 on check timetz

Tags: postgresql, centos

if anyone have some experience with compilation of Postgresql 13.0 from source on platform Centos 7,8 , and would you feel free to share the knowledges, please help me.
On both version I had problem with check "timetz" looks like:

```
...
    date                         ... ok         1948 ms
    time                         ... ok         1613 ms
    timetz                       ... FAILED     1631 ms
    timestamp                    ... ok         2133 ms
    timestamptz                  ... ok         2397 ms
    interval                     ... ok         2197 ms
    inet                         ... ok         2153 ms
...
```

I tried to change timezone to UTC etc. but without success. Maybe I totally wrong. If you know what is wrong, please let me know the hint or help.

Thanks folks!

Add to debug:
file: /home/release/src/postgresql-13.0/src/test/regress/results/timetz.out

```
SELECT '24:00:00.01'::timetz;  -- not allowed
ERROR:  date/time field value out of range: "24:00:00.01"
LINE 1: SELECT '24:00:00.01'::timetz;
               ^
SELECT '23:59:60.01'::timetz;  -- not allowed
ERROR:  date/time field value out of range: "23:59:60.01"
LINE 1: SELECT '23:59:60.01'::timetz;
               ^
SELECT '24:01:00'::timetz;  -- not allowed
ERROR:  date/time field value out of range: "24:01:00"
LINE 1: SELECT '24:01:00'::timetz;
               ^
SELECT '25:00:00'::timetz;  -- not allowed
ERROR:  date/time field value out of range: "25:00:00"
LINE 1: SELECT '25:00:00'::timetz;
               ^
--
-- TIME simple math
--
-- We now make a distinction between time and intervals,
-- and adding two times together makes no sense at all.
-- Leave in one query to show that it is rejected,
-- and do the rest of the testing in horology.sql
-- where we do mixed-type arithmetic. - thomas 2000-12-02
SELECT f1 + time with time zone '00:01' AS "Illegal" FROM TIMETZ_TBL;
ERROR:  operator does not exist: time with time zone + time with time zone
LINE 1: SELECT f1 + time with time zone '00:01' AS "Illegal" FROM TI...
                  ^
HINT:  No operator matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts.
```

Comment: It should show what caused the error in `src/test/regress/regression.diffs`. It failed here on openSUSE 15.1 also with diff of  `- 23:59:59.999999-07 + 23:59:59.999999-08`.  Per [here](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/regress-evaluation.html#id-1.6.19.6.8) the timezone is supposed to be set to `PST8PDT`.  My guess is the expected output was not changed to reflect change date  of `DST/ST` transition.

Answer (score 1):

A bug has been filed, see [here](https://www.postgresql.org/message-id/16697-b8bd875eb7dd9d48@postgresql.org). Should be fixed in next minor release.

Comment: Have anybody experiences or can anyone estimate the time of new release? Just for planning... If is better to wait for release or use older one. My task is prepare new age server with Pg for testing new production environment

Comment: See [here](https://www.postgresql.org/developer/roadmap/) for release schedule. `timetz` is basically useless and it was the test code that failed not the type so I would not worry about it.